# MySQL Statements

Tags: mysql, statements

I have been google-ing for the answer already, but can't really find good info. 
Its been a while I've played with `SQL` statements, but now i need it again.

Quick question: Is it possible to use the count statement in a insert statement? 
What i want to see is the following. Can't remember if this is possible, or its better with and IF/ELSE statement in between.

```
INSERT INTO tbltable (Row)
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbltable WHERE Row = "Hello" > 1)
VALUE "Value1";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. It's possible, but not like this.

Comment: Your syntax inert into ... when is incorrect for a start

Comment: It isn't obvious what exactly you want to insert. Can you describe more clearly what you want from this? It looks like you are trying to insert `'Value1'` only if `tbltable` already has `>1` for `Row = 'Hello'`. Is that correct?

Comment: The situation is the following: I have a PK that is a varchar (string). I don't want to have an insert when the PK already exists. So thats why i need the count. 
The syntax'es could be wrong, because i didn't copy pasted them. They are right in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbltable (ROW)
SELECT DISTINCT "Value1"
FROM tbltable
WHERE ROW = "Hello"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```